# Opening a pop up from angularjs partial page

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have an AngualarJS app that has an index page and some partial pages, displayed in `ui-view`. The app is using `ui-routing`. I have a button on the header (located on the index page) and on click of that button I want a small pop up open - a page displaying some data from the database, based on currently logged in user. I am trying to decide between opening a windows with window.open and sizing it to about 400x400 but that seems very un-elegant plus I see some issues with opening it. Another option I am entertaining is `bootstrap ui modal` but that would involve including bootstrap in my project on top of all the angular and routing includes.

Not sure if there is a better way to go, would appreciate any leads.

Comment: you can use window.open, can use bootstrap modal, can use whatever - what is question?

Comment: I am looking for the most elegant solution that is easiest to implement. I am new to Angular and there could easily be an easy solution that I am not aware of

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include bootstrap in your project You may use this one 
--> http://www.dwmkerr.com/the-only-angularjs-modal-service-youll-ever-need/

Comment: which Nuget package do i need to install? Don't seem to find angular modal service